# Get and set only public List<> member/field in a class/object

Tags: c#, list, reflection, unity-game-engine, field

I have an object/class, and I would like to get a list/array of any public List<> members/fields only for it.  And at a later point set those members.

currently I can get all the public fields with :

```
var fieldValues = obj[index].GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

and a bit of research says I can test GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>), tho I can't test this directly against the values returned in fieldValues.

So in summation, I want to get all the public fields for an object. Sort out the List<>, and set those members.

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this,

```
var fieldValues = test.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

foreach(var fieldValue in fieldValues)
{
    if (fieldValue.FieldType.IsGenericType && fieldValue.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        fieldValue.SetValue(test, new List<string>()
        {
            "List Item 1",
            "List Item 2"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an 'InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.MonoType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()' ? IsGenericType() doesn't throw an error, but don't believe it'll be as exact in sorting out List<>.

Comment: Are you using mono? What platform are you using?

Comment: I suspect your issue is specific to mono, as I don't have that issue here. What object are you running through the code above? I can try it out if you supply it.

Comment: its a "component" (attached class inheriting MonoBehaviour) of a Unity GameObject

Comment: OK in that case I can't try it. Sorry.